# Weekly org-capture-template without days?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'm hoping to replicate my manual weekly capture template using the more baked-in functionality.

Given this org-capture-template:

```
("z" "Test" entry (file+olp+datetree "~/docs/eng-log.org" "Worklog") "**** TODO %?" :tree-type week)
```

I'd like this output:

```
* Worklog
** 2020
*** 2020-W39
**** TODO testing?
```

Instead, I get this:

```
* Worklog
** 2020
*** 2020-W39
**** 2020-09-22 Tuesday
***** TODO testing?
```

Is there a way to remove the day marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the function `org-datetree-find-iso-week-create` and remove the part that add the day entry.

Here is the source of the original function:
https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-datetree.el#L111

Just remove the last `org-datetree--find-create` call.